# yum cannot update any repos and cannot install

Tags: centos, yum

I have recently installed centos 7 minimal version and trying to use `yum` to install other packages.
but yum is not working, i always see timeout error.
below are the files present in `/ect/yum.repos.d/`

```
CentOS-Base.repo  CentOS-CR.repo  CentOS-Debuginfo.repo  CentOS-fasttrack.repo  CentOS-Media.repo  
CentOS-Sources.repo  CentOS-Vault.repo
```

and

I have changed `enabled=0` to `enabled=1` by following a some portals and some random stuff to clean the repo list  and delete cache etc and `--disablerepo=epel` but none seems to work.

```
[root@labsw8 yum.repos.d]# yum --setopt=deltarpm=0 repolist all
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
http://vault.centos.org/7.0.1406/os/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 12] Timeout on http://vault.centos.org/7.0.1406/os/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: (28, 'Connection timed out after 30000 milliseconds')
Trying other mirror.
```

How can i figure out what exactly is the problem i tried to use EPEL repos but no EPEL repos are present under `/ect/yum.repos.d`, how to add them with out yum (since yum is not working)

Also, i suspect there is a firewall which is blocking requests, how can i figure out i am under any firewall?

EDIT: OK understood, as it is not connecting to outside world, it cannot download anything

If so, i can download RPMS of required packages and install manually, i tried installing tcpdump & pcap, but it has lot of dependencies like below

```
[root@labsw8 Downloads]# rpm -i libpcap-1.5.3-12.el7.i686.rpm
warning: libpcap-1.5.3-12.el7.i686.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID f4a80eb5: NOKEY
error: Failed dependencies:
        libc.so.6 is needed by libpcap-14:1.5.3-12.el7.i686
        libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.0) is needed by libpcap-14:1.5.3-12.el7.i686
        libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.1) is needed by libpcap-14:1.5.3-12.el7.i686
```

I request you to point me in right direction where i can get all dependencies or a way to install all dependencies without `yum`

EDIT 2: Luckily tcpdump and pcap are installed on the system , verified libs in /usr/lib64/, i see same files present in both working and non working machines
but non-working machine i get the error when i run

```
[root@labsw8 lib64]# tcpdump
tcpdump: Couldn't find user 'tcpdump'
```

do i need to update any path or something to make it work?

Comment: Your CentOS is doing fine and no one knows what your firewall is and how it's set up.

Comment: I am struck here, any way to confirm it is because of firewall, any pointers to check everything that is required for yum to work, other than firewall block.

Comment: `ping 8.8.8.8` `curl https://google.com` (or wget) for a start

Comment: tried ping 8.8.8.8 , its not pinging 100% packet loss.

Comment: updated the question, request not to down vote , i have not done this kind of activity before, and will be great full for any pointers in resolving the issue.

Comment: Installing RPMs manually is quite a complicated task. If you fire up a similar copy of CentOS somewhere else, you can enable yum caching and then copy RPMs after installing them.

Comment: @sravs The information regarding package dependencies is present inside the packages themselves. So when you download one package as a dependency, there's always a chance that it requires more packages. Ideally, you would use a system connected to the internet to get the full set of packages (RPMs in this case). You can use the `yumdownloader` command for this. Then, transfer those RPMs to the airgapped system and install.

Comment: It's weird he wants to install libpcap which is meant to work with a network, yet he actively firewalls the system in question.

Comment: this supposed work with in local network, already have some systems working, but its  long time back

Answer (score 0):

For the error `tcpdump: Couldn't find user 'tcpdump'`
we need to do the following to make it work.

open `/etc/passwd` and add the below line to it.

```
tcpdump:x:1001:1001::/home/tcpdump:/bin/bash
```

After that its working with root

Comment: Manually editing `/etc/passwd` is highly not recommended.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov, as i see that the difference between working and not working,  i have added it there, can you please let me know how the entry will be added there?